# Understand the output of console.trace() in Node

Tags: node.js

From the command line, typing `console.trace()` will spit out:

```
at repl:1:10
at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
at ReadStream._emitKey (tty.js:309:10)
```

Could someone quickly walk me trough this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a print from your current stack. Apparently you called `console.trace()` from some script that was called by `eval()` in `repl.js (line 80, column 20)`, that was called by `repl.js line 182`, that was called by `events.js (line 67)`, etc. etc. You have to read it top down.

Comment: Thanks. What is the very first line: `at repl:1:10`?

Comment: repl is the name of your javascript file from where you are calling the `eval`. So the new scope in node.js will be named to the file from where you are eval'ing. It could be that the first line, col 10 of your eval script throws the exception but these results can be quite unpredictable so it's probably somewhere else.